# ActionBarSherlock - Tab Navigation errors related to method override

Tags: java, android, tabs, actionbarsherlock, overriding

I'm trying to implement Tab Navigation using ActionBarSherlock within my app. I've started with testing the code from [this example](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock-samples/demos/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos/TabNavigation.java) in my app but it gives me errors related to the `@Override` methods (everything else seems to work fine, I also didn't have any problems with ActionBarSherlock in the same project before):

> The method onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction
>   transaction) of type ReportActivity must override or implement a
>   supertype method
>
> The method onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction
>   transaction) of type ReportActivity must override or implement a
>   supertype method
>
> The method onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction
>   transaction) of type ReportActivity must override or implement a
>   supertype method

I've tried changing     public void `onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction)` to `onTabSelected(com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction)` but it didn't help. I'm targeting my app to **API level 17**, which from what I've heard shouldn't be a problem for ActionBarSherlock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watch your imports!

My best guess is, that you imported the wrong `ActionBar.Tab`. Be sure to import everything from com.actionbarsherlock and android support lib, not the original api classes.

Comment: You're right, I had `android.app.FragmentTransaction` imported, where I should import `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction`.